# Parse a unique CSV format Snowflake COPY INTO

Tags: csv, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a csv file formatted like below and I am trying parse into snowflake.
Currently my file format looks like this:

```
file_format = (type = 'csv'
                  field_delimiter = ','
                  skip_header = 1
                  null_if = ('NULL', 'null')
                  empty_field_as_null = true
                  skip_blank_lines = TRUE
                  trim_space = TRUE
                  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'
```

My csv example is below, I can handle the "Supervisor" column by the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"' parameter. However, this throws off the "Customer_name" column since there is " " usually around the middle name and sometimes only one ".

```
"Supervisor","ID","Customer_name","Deleted"
"Abrhama, Thomas","280397212","Alibaba "Trey" Jones",""
"Susan, Smith","290940940","Sarah Rose" Miller",""
```

This is what my ideal table would look like.

```
 Supervisor          ID       Customer_name            Deleted
Abrhama, Thomas  280397212   Alibaba "Trey" Jones
Susan, Smith     290940940    Sarah Rose" Miller
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you'll need a custom parser. You can do that inside of Snowflake.

The first thing you want to do is bring the whole line into Snowflake as a single column. To do that, specify a table with only one column. For the column delimiter in the file format, you can use a symbol that you'll never encounter including a multi-char delimiter.

Then run the resulting table through a custom parser, such as this user defined table function:

```
create or replace temp table csv(line string);
create or replace temp table people(supervisor string, ID number, customer_name string, deleted string);

insert into csv select $$"Abrhama, Thomas","280397212","Alibaba "Trey" Jones",""$$;
insert into csv select $$"Susan, Smith","290940940","Sarah Rose" Miller",""$$;

-- Start with a table like this before running through the UDTF:
select * from csv;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PARSE_CSV(LINE string)
    RETURNS TABLE (supervisor string, id string, customer_name string, deleted string)
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS 
$${
        processRow: function f(row, rowWriter, context){
        
           var s = parseRow(row.LINE);
        
           rowWriter.writeRow({SUPERVISOR: s[0], ID: s[1], CUSTOMER_NAME: s[2], DELETED: s[3]});

        function parseRow(s) {
            var c = 0;
            var out = new Array(4);
            var p = s.split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                if (p[i].charAt(p[i].length - 1) != '"') {
                    out[c++] = p[i].substring(1) + p[i+1].substring(0, p[i+1].length - 1);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    out[c++] = p[i].substring(1, p[i].length - 1);
                }
            }
            return out;
        }
    }
}
$$;

select   SUPERVISOR
        ,ID
        ,CUSTOMER_NAME
        ,DELETED
from csv, lateral(table(parse_csv(LINE)));

-- You can then insert from that select:
insert into people
select   SUPERVISOR
        ,ID::int
        ,CUSTOMER_NAME
        ,DELETED
from csv, lateral(table(parse_csv(LINE)));
```

Comment: I am going to try this and did not know this was possible! Thank you! I will post again if this works!

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you would need to have a valid csv file, which is not what you have at the moment.

If you want to have double-quote characters within a field then you would need to include escape characters in your data and update your file format definition to reflect this.

Alternatively, not surrounding this specific field with double-quotes might work, but only if no instances of this field ever contained a comma

Comment: what about if this is .txt file instead of csv?

Comment: You mean just change the file extension? The problem is with the mal-formed contents of your file, not with its name, so no, changing the file name won't help

Comment: Changing the filed delimiter to a pipe or something else which is not a character within the data itself can help in this case.